# jQuery add Year(s) to date

Tags: jquery, date

I am using a datepicker and have a startdate, contractlength (Years) and enddate. These are all input fields. When a startdate is selected along with a contractlength it should calculate the end date.

So if startdate is 01/02/2013 and contractlength is 2 (Years) it should calculate the endate is 31/01/2015. I have created some jQuery and am very close, but just can not get the endate to calculate correctly when grabbing the contractlength from the input.

HTML

```
<label>Start Date:</label>
<input type='text' name='startdate' id='startdate' />

<label>Contract Length (Year):</label>
<input type='text' name='contractlength' id='contractlength' />

<label>End Date:</label>
<input type='text' name='EndDate' id='EndDate' />
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
$( "#startdate, #EndDate" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,

    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        if(this.id == 'startdate'){
            var ContractTerm = $('#contractlength').val();
            //var ContractTerm = 2;

            var dateMin = $('#startdate').datepicker("getDate");
            var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear() + ContractTerm, dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() - 1); 
            $('#EndDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(rMax)));                    
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(function() {
$( "#startdate, #EndDate" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,

    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        if(this.id == 'startdate'){
            var ContractTerm = $('#contractlength').val();
            //var ContractTerm = 2;

            var dateMin = $('#startdate').datepicker("getDate");
            var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear() + parseInt(ContractTerm), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() - 1); 
            $('#EndDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(rMax)));                    
        }
    }
});
});
```

See [jSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zWfmW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're concatating strings. `ContractTerm` is a string representing what's entered in the textbox. You have to convert that to a number:

```
var ContractTerm = +$('#contractlength').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
        now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 10);
        var futureYearLimit = now.getFullYear();

$( "#startdate, #EndDate" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    yearRange: "01/02/2013:" + futureYearLimit,
```