# jQuery UI Datepicker: Update expiration date by one year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to update a text field after selecting a date.  The date needs to be + 1 year from the selected date.

Here's [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sffk0a5d/3/):

```
var $dtStart = $('#dtStart');
var $dtEnd = $('#dtEnd');

$dtStart.datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var myDate = new Date(newdate);
        myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
        $dtEnd.val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', myDate));
        $dtEnd.focus();
    }
});
```

I'm using a suggestion from [a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790211/jquery-add-years-to-date) but can't seem to get them to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Be specific about what is not working and what you have tried to work through the problem.

Comment: Figured it out http://jsfiddle.net/sffk0a5d/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `newdate` as an argument in the function you pass to onSelect (`onSelect: function(newdate) {`):

```
var $dtStart = $('#dtStart');
var $dtEnd = $('#dtEnd');
$dtStart.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(newdate) {
        var myDate = new Date(newdate);
        myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
        $dtEnd.val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', myDate));
        $dtEnd.focus();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sffk0a5d/4/)**